# Facebook Login button stopped rendering

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a test page where I am trying to work out the problems of the Facebook Login button.  I tried something, put things back to how they were, and now the button stopped rendering.

The page is here:
http://www.comehike.com/test_fb_connect.php

Any idea why the button doesn't show up?

Comment: Is it the one on top? It's rendering here.

Answer (score 3):

First, clear your browser's cache and cookies. A commenter stated that the button renders for him/her, so it could be a local issue.

Second ensure that your Facebook developer account is active.

Third, use Firebug to check the requests between your site and Facebook. This may reveal any obvious errors.

Comment: This is basically it, but let me just add that from experience, Facebook's APIs can be finnicky at times and there may be nothing wrong with your code or setup. I've had a "Like" button suddenly not rendering for 80% of my users with various browsers, OSes and whatever and then being "fixed" with no intervention from my part about two weeks later.

Comment: @neves Hmmm, take a look at this url: http://www.comehike.com/index_alex.php - it refreshes all the time for me on Firefox.  It doesn't do that to you?

Comment: @GeekedOut Nope, everything looks fine here.